Occasionally, when using free case law databases, certain cases may be missing or have incomplete texts. What should I do in such situations?
I am researching American legal precedents, often tracing them back to the early 20th century. I typically use the CourtListener free case law database, but sometimes my searches yield no results or the text is incomplete. In such cases, do you rely on other free databases to supplement your research? If you don't mind, could you also share tips on how to handle these situations effectively? The American legal system is unique globally, so as a foreigner, I would greatly appreciate any insights into mastering effective search techniques.
